# Procedure Error: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql

The procedure takes two dates and find the reports that issued during this duration, and update total salary, and print them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Salary_Update(p_Date1 DATE, p_Date2 DATE) AS 
CURSOR MYCR IS 
SELECT ReportID, TotalSale, Rate, TotalSalary, ReportDate
FROM WEEKLY_REPORT
WHERE ReportDate BETWEEN TO_DATE(p_Date1, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(p_Date2, 'DD-MM-YYYY'); 
BEGIN
FOR MYPOINTER IN MYCR LOOP
UPDATE WEEKLY_REPORT SET TotalSalary = ((TotalSale/100)*Rate);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total salary for report ' || MYPOINTER.REPORTID || '  updated to ' || MYPOINTER.TotalSalary || 'dollars, which is ' || MYPOINTER.Rate || '% of the total sale of ' || MYPOINTER.TotalSale || 'dollars.');
WHERE ReportID = MYPOINTER.ReportID;
END LOOP;
END Salary_Update;
/
```

the execution

```
BEGIN Salary_Update('02-04-2020','05-04-2020');
END;
BEGIN 
Salary_Update(to_date('02-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'), to_date('05-04-2020','dd-mm-yyyy'));
END;
```

both don't work.

Comment: Do `show errors` after compilation, or query `user_errors`, to see what is wrong. Your update has `:=` instead of `=`, for a start.

Comment: @AlexPoole I use oracle apex. show error doesn't work

Comment: You can query `user_errors` as @AlexPoole suggested.  You're making a `to_date` call on a `date` which doesn't make sense in addition to the error in the `update`.  Your `update` statement updates every row of the table because there is no `where` clause.  It really doesn't make sense to open a cursor that iterates over every row in the table and then have an `if` statement in the loop that filters out most of the rows.  That should be a `where` clause in the cursor definition.

Comment: Your input parameters are defined as DATE, but when you call the procedure, you are giving strings.  DATE is an internal, binary data type.

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT is fine for debugging, but not for formal reporting.  It does _not_ write to the screen.  It writes to an internal buffer.  That buffer is then passed back to the calling program _after_ completion of the procedure, when operational control returns to the caller.  It is then up to the caller to decide whether or not to process the buffer.  And some calling programs may not even be programmed to be able to process it.

Comment: @JustinCave thank you, I changed the type to varchar2 but where should I add `WHERE REPORTID = MYPOINTER.REPORTID` between the update and print? or before end if?

Comment: You have an extra `(` in `IF (MYPOINTER.ReportDate`. Remove the opening bracket. Also, in `UPDATE WEEKLY_REPORT SET TotalSalary :=` it should be `=` not `:=`.

Comment: _"I changed the type to varchar2"_  Well, we don't know exactly what/where you changed.  There are several places where this comes into play.  Please update you question to show your new code.  Keep in mind that comparisons of "dates" that are actually strings won't work. In string comparisons, '02-04-2020' comes _before_ (evalueates to "less than")   '03-04-2019'.

Comment: @JustinCave the error showed "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" I only use single table and 100% it is exists, the cursor showed the required data, but I think the problem with the body. I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I have changed it, I even deleted the if statement but still get same error.

Comment: OK.  You're getting an ORA-00942 error.  On which line?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of syntax and logic errors.  You haven't specified exactly what you want the code to do or provided a reproducible test case but my guess is that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Salary_Update(
  p_Date1 DATE, 
  p_Date2 DATE) 
AS 
  CURSOR MYCR IS 
    SELECT ReportID, TotalSale, Rate, TotalSalary, ReportDate
      FROM WEEKLY_REPORT
     WHERE ReportDate BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2;
BEGIN
  FOR MYPOINTER IN MYCR 
  LOOP
    UPDATE WEEKLY_REPORT 
       SET TotalSalary = ((TotalSale/100)*Rate)
     WHERE ReportID = MYPOINTER.ReportID;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total salary for report ' || MYPOINTER.REPORTID || '  updated to ' || MYPOINTER.TotalSalary || 'dollars, which is ' || MYPOINTER.Rate || '% of the total sale of ' || MYPOINTER.TotalSale || 'dollars.');
  END LOOP;
END Salary_Update;
/
```

The string you're outputting doesn't seem to make sense-- `MYPOINTER.TotalSalary` is the value from the cursor which will be the value from before the update.  If it is important that you print out the value you updated `TotalSalary` to, you'd probably want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Salary_Update(
  p_Date1 DATE, 
  p_Date2 DATE) 
AS 
  CURSOR MYCR IS 
    SELECT ReportID, TotalSale, Rate, TotalSalary, ReportDate
      FROM WEEKLY_REPORT
     WHERE ReportDate BETWEEN p_date1 AND p_date2;
  l_newSalary weekly_report.totalSalary%type;
BEGIN
  FOR MYPOINTER IN MYCR 
  LOOP
    l_newSalary := (mypointer.TotalSale/100) * mypointer.rate;
    UPDATE WEEKLY_REPORT 
       SET TotalSalary = l_newSalary
     WHERE ReportID = MYPOINTER.ReportID;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total salary for report ' || MYPOINTER.REPORTID || '  updated to ' || l_newSalary || 'dollars, which is ' || MYPOINTER.Rate || '% of the total sale of ' || MYPOINTER.TotalSale || 'dollars.');
  END LOOP;
END Salary_Update;
/
```

If the error that you're getting is an ORA-00942 error that `weekly_report` doesn't exist, then there is no such table in the current schema.  Assuming that the query works when run interactively, potentially the table exists in a different schema, there is a local synonym in the current schema for that table, and the owner of the procedure only has access to the table granted via a role.  In that case, you'd need your DBA to grant access to the table directly to the owner of the procedure.